# Issue with WHERE email NOT IN (%s) using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a project using php and mysql, I have following sql query that was working fine before I added the NOT IN in the WHERE clause

```
$excludeEmail = 'abc@gmail.com','def@hotmail.com','u2u@xyz.com';
$result = $mSearch->dao->query(sprintf('
SELECT id
FROM(
    SELECT id, date 
    FROM table 
    WHERE email NOT IN (%s) 
    AND b_enabled=1 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20) AS t1 
ORDER BY date ASC 
LIMIT 2
', $excludeEmail ));
```

Please tell me what is wrong with it.

It do not select any row from the table.

**Edit**

I think there is something wrong in my sub query, let me explain what I expect from sub query

I need 20 rows from the table having largest values in the “id” field

These rows should not contain any email address that I provided through variable $excludeEmail,

These rows should not contain 1 in the b_enabled field.

**Issue**

The main issue is if there is no email address in variable $excludeEmail it selects no row from the table.

Comment: try replacing NOT IN with NOT LIKE '%S'

Comment: ^ NOT LIKE can only be done with one specific string. This won't help.

Comment: Print the query after you do the variable substitution.  I think the answer will be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have quotations around your exclude variable:

```
$excludeEmail = "'abc@gmail.com','def@hotmail.com','u2u@xyz.com'";
```

Comment: Your explanation isn't too great, but I removed my answer since you were 10 seconds faster.

Comment: thank you for answer, adding the quotations did not help me, please check edited question.